# Whats the difference between the css classes like a.first and .first a?

Tags: css

Can you explain me css difference between `a .someclass`, `.someclass a` or something like, `img .someclass` and `.someclass img`?

Comment: I couldn't tell if the comma was supposed to be part of the selector, or whether you were listing them, please correct my changes if I made them incorrectly.

Comment: it wasnt.. u r right now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a .someclass
```

Selects any (descendant of an 'a' tag) that has a class of 'someclass'

```
<a href="#example">
    <span class="someclass">...</span>
</a>
```

While

```
.someclass a
```

Selects any (descendant of a tag with a class of 'someclass') that is an 'a' tag.

```
<div class="someclass">
    <a href="...">...</a>
</div>
```

And

```
a.someclass /* Note absence of spaces */
```

Selects any 'a' tag with a class of 'someclass'.

```
<a href="..." class="someclass">...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

`a .someclass` matches on elements with a class of `someclass` that are within an anchor element:

```
<a href="#example">
   <span class="someclass">...</span><!-- this one is matched -->
</a>
```

`.someclass a` matches on anchors that are within elements with a class of `someclass`:

```
<span class="someclass">
    <a href="#example">...</a><!-- this one is matched -->
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

think of it like an order of operations as you move down through the dom tree. For example, `a .someclass /* space in between */` would be applied to the following:

```
<a href="">
   <span class="someclass"></span>
</a>
```

while `.someclass a /* space in between */` would be applied to the following:

```
<div class="someclass">
   <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a .someclass
```

will match this span:

```
<a><span class="someclass"></span></a>
```

--

```
.someclass a
```

will match this span:

```
<a class="someclass"><span></span></a>
```

--

> or something like, img .someclass and .someclass img?

See above but swap the `a` tag for an `img` tag

Answer (score 0):

a.first would select any  tag with the class of first**
.first a would select any  tag that is a child of an element with the class of "first"

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the order applied. When there is a list of selectors separated by a space, it indicates a parent child relationship, where the former selector is the parent, and the latter is the child. This continues on down the chain if there are more than 2 selectors.

When you use

```
img .className { /* style rules */ }
```

it will look for all elements which have `class="className"` and are nested inside of an image tag. ( All `.className` which are children of `img` )

However, when you use

```
.className img { /* style rules */ }
```

it will look for all image tags which are nested inside of an element with `class="className"`. ( All `img` which are children of `.className` )

Comment: this is nice expln :) and wat about img.classname?